# Confusion of the difference in the geometry of a cylinder and a sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am studying Riemannian geometry and reading the book: Introduction to smooth manifolds by J.Lee.

Let's consider the cylinder $x^2 +y^2 =1$ and the unit sphere $x^2 +y^2 +z^2 =1$. Both are embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the induced metric from  $\mathbb{R}^3$. Apparently, the geometry of a cylinder is not the same as the geometry of a sphere. In Lee's book he wrote that:  "the induced metric on the cylinder is flat", *but the induced metric on the sphere is not.*

To emphasize the flatness on the cylinder, he also wrote that: "A two-dimensional being living in the cylinder would not be able to distinguish its surroundings from the Euclidean plane by local geometric measurements." Can someone give me a detailed explanation on this point? What does he mean by "local geometric measurements"? Since in my mind, on the surface of the sphere, locally, we can also not distinguish the surroundings from the Euclidean plane.

Thank.

Comment: You can distinguish a sphere from a plane, up to *isometry*, by drawing triangles; on a sphere you can draw triangles whose angles add up to more than $180^{\circ}$. This doesn't happen on a cylinder because a cylinder can be "unrolled" to a plane.

Comment: @Yuan, Thank you. I think I quite got it now. What is the relation between "flatness" and "curvature"? Is it ok to think that flatness = zero curvature? Is "curvature" a local concept, i.e. we attach a number (curvature) to each point?

Comment: On the cylinder, if you walk "up" and then "left" the same amount, you'll land in the same place had you walked left then up, relative to the induced metric from $\mathbb{R}^3$.  On the sphere this isn't the case; this is what the lie algebra associated with the metric is measuring.  This is probably what he's getting at, if my recollection of the book is accurate.

Comment: @Hana: yes, flatness means zero curvature, and curvature is local. This is a key point in Riemannian geometry and will be explained if you keep reading the book. Formally, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature

Comment: There is an intuitive (but at heart rigorous) way to see this: You can take a flat sheet of paper and roll it into a cylinder without tearing, crumpling or distorting, hence the cylinder is "flat". But if you want to cover a sphere, you cannot, so the sphere is not.